# Prime $p$ such that $\dfrac{p+1}{6}$ is prime and $p+1$ is divisible by $9$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am in search for a prime number $p$ with the following two properties:

1) $\dfrac{p+1}{6}$ is prime;

2) $p+1$ should contain $3^2$ or higher powers of 3.

**Example**: 17 is prime. $\dfrac{17+1}{6}=3$ is a prime. $17+1=18=2\times 3^2$.

The following is my *JULIA code* and I am getting only 17,  is there any theorem stating such numbers does not exist **other than 17** or else please provide me any **counter example** of such number.

```
       for i=1:10000000000000000000000
              if isprime(i) && mod(i+1,9)==0 && isprime(convert(BigInt,(i+1)/6))
              print(i, " ")
              end
       end
```

Comment: If $p+1$ contains higher power of 3, than $\frac{p+1}6$ is divisible by 3, because 6 only contains 3 once. So $\frac{p+1}6=3$, for it to be prime.

Comment: I changed the title of your question in order to make it a little more readable, and then realized that the answer was already embedded in that title.

Comment: To elaborate o the previous comment, if $p+1$ is divisible by $9$, then $(p+1)/6$ is either divisible by $3$ or not integer at all. In both cases, it is not a prime.

Comment: The number $17$ works as 3 is a prime number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p+1=k3^n$ for some $k,n\ge2$. We have $$\frac{p+1}{6}=\frac{k}{2}3^{n-1}.$$ Can you see why this is not going to be prime for $k>2$ and any $n\ge2$?